# Get start time and end time of Flag=1, if it repeats 4 times (without using for loop)

Tags: r

I am new to R and stuck in getting Get start time and end time of Flag=1. The condition is, 1 should repeat (consecutively) at least 4 times then only its start and end time needs to be captured. My input looks like-

`Time Stamp    Flag
00:00:00        1
00:00:10        1
00:00:20        1
00:00:30        1
00:00:40        0
00:00:50        0
00:01:00        0
00:01:10        0
00:01:20        0
00:01:30        1
00:01:40        1
00:01:50        1
00:02:00        0
00:02:10        1
00:02:20        1
00:02:30        1
00:02:40        1
00:02:50        1
00:03:00        1
00:03:10        1
00:03:20        1`

and my output should look like -

`Start Time End Time    Duration
00:00:00    00:00:30    00:00:30
00:02:10    00:03:20    00:01:10`

I have achieved it using for loop and if else, but as the data is huge its taking lots of time. So, I need to optimize it.

Is there any inbuilt function in R that i can modify and use?

Answer (score 0):

First create the data using:

```
st <- data.frame(Time = format(seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 00:00:00", tz="UTC"),
                                     to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1  00:03:20", tz="UTC"), 
                               by="10 secs") , "%H:%M:%S" ), 
                 Flag = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

st$Time <- as.POSIXct(st$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Using `dplyr` I would approach this as:

```
st %>% 
mutate(gr = cumsum(lag(Flag, default = Flag[1]) != Flag)) %>%
filter(Flag == 1) %>%
group_by(gr) %>%
filter(length(gr) >= 4) %>% 
summarise(start.time = first(Time),
          last.time  = last(Time)) %>%
mutate(Duration = last.time - start.time)
```

The result is

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
     gr          start.time           last.time Duration
  <int>              <dttm>              <dttm>   <time>
1     0 2017-06-08 00:00:00 2017-06-08 00:00:30  30 secs
2     4 2017-06-08 00:02:10 2017-06-08 00:03:20  70 secs
```